# Statistical Responses/tests for Yes/No, Pre/Post surveys

Tags: mathematical-statistics, p-value, standard-deviation, dataset, research-design

I am completing a research paper regarding clinician adherence to a protocol. One of the questions is whether or not they use adjuctive therapy to the treatment. I have a pre and post survey, yes/no responses. I had 6/11 say yes on the pre survey and 11/11 say yes on the post survey.
My professor is wanting to know standard deviation and p-value of this data. I cant figure out the correct stats yet and values that I am looking for. They aren't means so that rules out t-tests right? Im so lost. Help please!

Comment: This is probably chi-square test